# Word for moving quickly enough for things to seem blurry

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe an anecdote, but want to use a word to describe the time period. So in physics when you move quickly enough to approach the speed of light, time breaks down and relativity kicks in. I want to describe a period in the past that I was moving so quickly at the time (such as through college) that the events seem to mesh together. Like a very, very fast moving object in relativity. Preferably a single word I can use such as

> I was moving _____ so everything was unclear.

Or

> I was moving like a ____ so everything seems to mesh together.

Or

> I was so ____ that everything seems blurry now.

Naturally I can just give the long winded physics explanation, but that's extremely verbose, and distracts from the subject matter because the need to explain what the metaphor is directly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109806/discussion-on-question-by-uberhaxed-word-for-moving-quickly-enough-for-things-to).

Comment: I was racing so quickly that everything was/(is?) a bit of a blur.

Comment: Anything wrong with "in a blur"?  (Other than the fact that some might believe this is referring to your mental condition?)

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, would just use a different metaphor; using speed about foggy memories is sort of confusing, and I doubt there's a good word to use; maybe something more like about how much was happening in your life?

Answer (score 0):

*Zap past* could work in that context, as in, "college zapped past me like I was looking out a fast moving car."

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more descriptive verb in place of "was moving."

> I **rocketed / was rocketing** so fast that...

**rocket** (v.)

> *Intransitive. gen.* To move like a rocket; esp. to move rapidly; to travel at great speed. Frequently with adverb of direction. OED

> To travel rapidly in or as if in a rocket [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rocket)

---

> Batting left-handed, Mantle took his usual vicious swing, and when the
> ball hit the bat, it **rocketed** toward the outfield **so fast that** the
> Yankees sitting on the bench almost got whiplash jerking their heads
> to the right. [Tony Castro; *Mickey Mantle*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mickey_Mantle/w98PDLmfLacC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=rocketed%20by%20so%20fast%20that&pg=PA1824&printsec=frontcover)

> Either he is a genius who graduated law school before puberty or he's
> a trust-fund baby who was **rocketed through school** because his
> father made a donation for a new library wing. [Addison Plaisance;
> *Social Media Destruction*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Social_Media_Destruction/gbjADwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22rocketed%20through%20school%22&pg=PT96&printsec=frontcover)